# Using vector of index on multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array `A` of size 500x14. I have a vector of indexes `Ind` of size 500. The vector stores desired index for each row of A.

I want to extract the following:
`A[0,:][Ind[0]]` and so on

I am trying `out = A[Ind]` to give me an output of size 500 but it gives me output of size 500x14.

Comment: You need fancy (or advanced) indexing: `out = A[range(I.size),I]`.

Comment: Love the 3 levels of duplicates - can we make it 4, 5?